Non-nullable field in schema does not prevent null values in corresponding table column
I have read the documentation of the field() method, and as far as I understand I can say that a field does not allow NULL values by specifying nullable=False. So, I have tried this example:
schema = pyarrow.schema(fields=[
    pyarrow.field(name='unique_id', type=pyarrow.uint64(), nullable=False),
    pyarrow.field(name='age', type=pyarrow.uint8(), nullable=True),
    pyarrow.field(name='favourite_colours', type=pyarrow.list_(pyarrow.string()), nullable=True)
])
data = [
    [1, None, 3],
    [10, None, 30],
    [None, ['red', 'blue'], ['green']]
]
table = pyarrow.table(data=data, schema=schema)
print(table)


I declare the field unique_id as nullable=False, and therefore I was expecting some sort of error when building the pyarrow.table, where I pass data with a NULL value for unique_id ([1, None, 3] in the code example).
Am I doing something wrong? I'm using pyarrow 17.0.0 with Python 3.8.16

the nullable fields are not very well enforced sadly. For instance table.validate() works, but table.cast(table.schema) fails. I think there are issues for this in Arrow's github repo, but I don't think it's a simple fix.

Thank you @0x26res ... this is not very nice. Do you know if it is possible to contact someone from the PyArrow community? Should I open a bug?

As mentioned there's already a lot of issues about this eg https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/43146 and https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/41667
